# How to appeal being banned from Facebook for 'fake name'

Tags: facebook

My step-son tried to log in to Facebook and saw that account was disabled.  Supposedly because he was using a fake name, which he wasn't.  Is there any way to appeal it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this at Facebook's help center: [Why was my personal Facebook account disabled?](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=1581) At the end, it says

> If you believe your account was
>   disabled by mistake, click [**here**](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=disabled).

That link takes you to a form you can use to request re-enabling the account.

It's possible that Facebook will *not* care about the requests though. :/ The question reminded me of a [newspaper article](http://www.hs.fi/kotimaa/artikkeli/Ville+Valon+kokonimikaiman+Facebook-tili+suljettiin+ilman+selityksi%C3%A4/1135259756203) (in Finnish; [very bad Google translation here](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=auto&tl=en&twu=1&u=http://www.hs.fi/kotimaa/artikkeli/1135259756203) — 'valo' means 'light') about someone whose name real name is Ville Valo (i.e. he's the namesake of a well-known [rock artist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ville_Valo)) who got his FB account disabled, and Facebook just refused to listen to his pleas to re-open it.

Answer (score -1):

provide a birth certificate, library card,or school id card and then take a picture with a webcam or phone and save to your computer and upload it and your  account should be enabled